# using form.csrf_token with jinja macro is not hiding the csrf_token field

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

this is macro that I put together:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<!--ctrl+alt+shift+J-->
 {{field.label}}
    {{field(required=False)}}
    <ul>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
           <li style="color:red">{{error}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

this is how I used in index.html template:

```
 <form action="/" method="POST">
    {{render_field(form.username)}}
    {{render_field(form.email)}}
    {{render_field(form.password)}}
    {{render_field(form.age)}}
    {{render_field(form.true)}}
    {{render_field(form.csrf_token)}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

all other fields work as expected but this is what I got for csrf token. csrf token field is not hidden.

[image]

i added this to macro:

```
{{field(**kwargs)|safe}}
```

then add in index.html

```
{{render_field(form.csrf_token(hidden=True))}}
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flask-WTForms [`hidden tag`](http://%20%3Cform%20action=%22/%22%20method=%22POST%22%3E):

```
 <form action="/" method="POST">
     {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     ...
 </form>
```